# glut sphere appear stretched when using non-square resolutions

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry, glut

I have a code:

```
void kula(void)
{
  glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
  glutSolidSphere(0.2, 100.0, 100.0); 
  glFlush();
}
```

Next:

```
void Display()
{
..
kula();
..
}
```

When the window size is 600x600 the sphere is ok. But when the window size is not a square, for example 600x800 instead of the sphere is flattened egg. How do I deal with it?

Answer (score 2):

It's a little hard to know without seeing your complete initialisation process, but I'll take a guess.

You are probably not setting up your projection matrix according your resolution, the `gluPerspective` can help you with that. You should call it whatever there's a windows resize event, like this:

```
glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective( field_of_view, (double)w/h, zner, zfar );
```

Those links can help you

- [glutPerspective](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml)
- [How can I prevent the viewport from stretching/distorting?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/81893/how-can-i-prevent-the-viewport-from-stretching-distorting)